# Laravel 4.2, passing the value by $id

Tags: php, laravel

I have my unique C_id value stored in $c_id.for eg.my C_id is 4 and that value is stored in $c_id. so I have to retrieve image which belongs to that C_id. how can i do that??

Comment: We need some more information, we don't know what your C_id is supposed to be or where your image might be, do you have the image in a database or the path to the image in the database etc.

Comment: do you want to retrieve your image from view or from controller itself?

Comment: i have my table images in which C_id,image is stored. so i have retrieved the C_id value in $C_id so have to retrieve image equal to that $C_id...